# My Info PHP substr problems

Tags: php, substr

What i am doing is a personal information profile.  It's nothing to complicated but i am trying to pull initials from 3 different strings and I just cant figure it out. I put an image of my code up, any info would be awesome. I'm not looking for someone to do it, just give me some hints and point me in the general direction.

```
        echo "<br>";
        $firstName = "Harvey";
        $middleName = "Joseph";
        $lastName = "Glick";
        $fullName = $firstName . " " . $middleName . " " . $lastName;
        $initialsName = substr($fullName, 0, -9);    // needs some work
        $houseNumber = "110";
        $street = "Jones Street";
        $streetAddress = $houseNumber . " " . $street;     // needs some work
```

Comment: Why would you put an image of your code???

Comment: Add the code to your question. C'mon.

Comment: You need to run `substr` on each name value and then concatenate all 3 together.

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP site http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: my first time posting on here, so i added my code straight from notepad ++ but the site wasnt accepting it. one second let me try and add it again

Comment: guys take it easy he is new here. no need for harassment

Comment: H. J. Glick      so i have to pull that information from the first name, middle name, and last name string. I believe.    That is were i am stuck, am i able to run substr on one line for all three of those items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `substr` on each name part, not after joining all three parts together.

As is you are taking the first character of the `fullname`. Which would be the same as just taking the first character of the `firstname`.

As a rough example:

```
$first = 'GivenName';
$mid = 'Middle';
$surname = 'Surname';
$f_initial = substr($first, 0, 1);
$m_initial = substr($mid, 0, 1);
echo $f_initial . ' ' . $m_initial . ' ' . $surname;
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/FsEQO

Note: the image you had and the text you've updated are different. This

```
substr($fullName, 0, -9);
```

Is starting from the right of the string and going `9` characters in. The `, 0, 1)` was closer. You also could accomplish this with a regex.

Alternative regex approach:

```
$firstName = "Harvey";
$middleName = "Joseph";
$lastName = "Glick";
$fullName = $firstName . " " . $middleName . " " . $lastName;
echo preg_replace('/([A-Z])[a-z]+\h+/', '$1 ', $fullName);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/mX0LH

Per the update, real example: https://3v4l.org/JiM7u

```
$firstName = "Harvey";
$middleName = "Joseph";
$lastName = "Glick";
$f_initial = substr($firstName, 0, 1);
$m_initial = substr($middleName, 0, 1);
echo $f_initial . ' ' . $m_initial . ' ' . $lastName;
```

Comment: thank you. yeah the directions i received from my professor are really vague and im just trying to figure it out. thank you again

Comment: the reason the image is different is because that was what i originally typed, and after i posted i have been messing around and trying to figure it out. So the numbers were different.

Comment: Parameter 1 is the position, parameter 2 is the length. If parameter 2 is negative it starts at the right and goes left. So `0,1` is the start of the string and 1 character.

Comment: okay, that makes sense, i was just trying different stuff. Now i cant change any of the other lines just the one that says needs some work, which is the initialsName line, i can add lines, is that possible. Thanks again for helping, i do appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you very much, i went back in and typed it up and it worked. I guess i was reading to far into what the professor put on his pdf file, instead of trying to find a work around to make it work out.

Comment: Hmm so does this answer resolve your issue, or was the issue something different?

Comment: It did resolve my issue, Thank you again, i was able to figure it out. You put me in the right direction. opened my eyes a bit. i appreciate the help

Comment: Great, please accept the answer in that case so the question is resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers